# Shuffle a list items among dissimilar items

Tags: python, shuffle

How to shuffle list items keeping the similar items unshuffled? E.g. for the list 'L', I want to shuffle among the unique items.

```
L=[a,a,b,b,c,c,d,d]
```

For the above list, I want to get

```
shuffled_L=[c,c,a,a,d,d,b,b]
```

Comment: Group same items into lists or tuples, shuffle the groups, ungroup again…?

Comment: @deceze or make a counter, shuffle it and make list back from counter

Comment: @sudden Yes, depends on whether object identity is important or not…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group into tuples, shuffle the tuples, flatten the list again:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> L = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d"]
>>> L_ = [tuple(v) for _, v in groupby(L)]
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd')]
>>> random.shuffle(L_)
[('b', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('d', 'd'), ('c', 'c')]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(L_))
['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'c']
```

This assumes the original `L` is already sorted. If it isn't, `sort` it before the `groupby` step.

Answer (score 0):

applying @suddents_appearence method from the comments

```
>>> import random
>>> import itertools
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L=["a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d"]
>>> count=Counter(L)
>>> sample=random.sample(sorted(count),len(count))
>>> _shuffled_L=list(map(lambda x:[x]*count.get(x),sample))
>>> shuffled_L=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(_shuffled_L))
>>> shuffled_L
['d', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: Numpy as a dependency for something that can be solved fairly easily with builtins is… meh…